# Referencing a class library from a UWP app in a different solution

Tags: uwp, entity-framework-core, class-library, solution

I'm having problems adding a reference to a Universal Windows Class library from a UWP app that lives in a different solution.

Here's the setup:

```
Solution A
  Data Access Library (references EntityFramework.Commands nuget package)
  Test App

Solution B
  Production App
```

Consuming the data acccess library from the test app works perfectly fine (added via the Projects tab of the Add Reference dialog).

When I try to add a reference to the production app (via the browse button and selecting the DLL), that leads to the following compiler errors:

```
Payload file '[long path]\EntityFramework.Commands.dll' does not exist.
Payload file '[long path]\EntityFramework.Commands.xml' does not exist.
Payload file '[long path]\EntityFramework.Relational.Design.dll' does not exist.
Payload file '[long path]\EntityFramework.Relational.Design.xml' does not exist.
```

The files *do* exist though, I added the reference directly from the bin folder and they are all there. Neither adding these DLLs as references as well nor adding the EntityFramework.Commands nuget package to the production app does help.

Comment: Do you get an error in the references?

Comment: No, just the compiler errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to the new EF Core 1.0 release, that somehow solved the problem. I still don't know what *was* the problem though.